# Is there an algorithm to transform a combination of numbers into one number?

Tags: mysql, algorithm, combinations

I'm developing a survey-like application. For multiple-choice questions, I want to store a combination of items in one number to store it in one row.

So the database structure for questions is like this:

```
id    type                 text                      item_id
-- ---------------   ---------------------------     -------
1  multiple_choice   which one would you choose?        42
1  multiple_choice   which one would you choose?        43
1  multiple_choice   which one would you choose?        46
```

This is a question with 3 choices, the options will be called from another table *items*, with id's 42,43,46

so I want to turn this combination into one number to achieve this:

```
id    type                 text                      items
-- ---------------   ---------------------------     -------
1  multiple_choice   which one would you choose?        x*
```

- x should be a number that indicates it is derived from numbers 42,43,46

so mathematically it would be something like

```
f({42,43,46}) = x   and   f^-1(x)={42,43,46}
```

One way to solve this may be to use prime numbers as item id's. So that the multiplication of them is unique, but is there a way to do this with all numbers?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is there a maximum to your ids? In which case you can just concatenate them example if it 99:
42 + 43*100 + 46 * 10000...
Why one number? Why don't you do a string? comma separated for example?

Comment: @charly storing them in a comma-seperated string is a good idea. But I tried that earlier, and the problem with that was when I want to modify one member of a set (i.e. add/remove options to a question) it really becomes a headache with PHP. so I would really prefer to store the set as compact as possible.

Comment: even with `implode(,)` and `explode(,)` ?

Comment: yes, I mean than I have to turn that string into an array in PHP, in different places and in different forms. So I'm seeking for a single function that transform a number into a set, and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

No, no, no.  This is not what you want to do in a relational database.

Your original table for `questions` is closer to right approach.

If you want to get all the possible answers, just do the following query:

```
select id, type, text, group_concat(item_id)
from questions q
group by id, type, text;
```

But, what you should really have are two tables (at least).  Questions which lists each question and has columns such as:

- question_id
- type
- text

With *1* row per question (that is, `question_id` is a primary key).

And a second table `question_items`, with columns like:

- question_items_id
- question_id
- more information about the item

With this format, the above query would be more like:

```
select q.question_id, q.type, q.text, group_concat(qi.question_item_id)
from questions q join
     question_items qi
     on q.question_id = qi.question_id
group by q.question_id, q.type, q.text;
```

Although the query may look a bit more complicated, the underlying data structure better represents your problem domain.  This makes the overall system much more robust and maintainable.

Comment: Thanks, Gordon! I see what you are saying. This is called a "normalized approach" , right? but I'm too lazy to do that :) and really trying to find a way to store questions in only one table, if possible.

Comment: @void . . . Yes, this is a normalized approach.  If you really want to do that, then store the items as a comma separated list.  And, search for all the questions about parsing comma separated lists.  Doing things right (or at least "rightish") the first time is really the approach for lazy people.  It prevents lots of problems down the road and simplifies the entire development process.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the best way to go about this.  You should instead have a multiple table structure, i.e.

- *Questions* = 1 row per question, containing the text and question type
- *Items* = 1 row per item
- *QuestionHasItems* = 1 row per question per item

These names are just meant as illustration.  By going down the route you have started, the field "type", "id", and "text" is redundant and so very wasteful / inefficient.

If you check this example, then you will see the table structure prefilled and an example query.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fdf5f/4

The query as follows would then produce the data you wish

```
SELECT

  q.questionid,
  q.questiontype,
  q.questiontext,
  GROUP_CONCAT(i.itemid) AS itemIDs,
  GROUP_CONCAT(i.itemtext) AS itemTexts

FROM questions q

INNER JOIN questionHasItems qhi
ON qhi.questionid = q.questionid

INNER JOIN items i
ON i.itemid = qhi.itemid

GROUP BY q.questionid;
```

While allowing you to efficiently get, for example, options available to a question by doing queries such as

```
SELECT

  i.itemid AS itemIDs,
  i.itemtext AS itemTexts

FROM questionHasItems qhi

INNER JOIN items i
ON i.itemid = qhi.itemid

WHERE qhi.questionid = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks! But I don't like the idea of having an extra table. I really want to store questions in one table. But if I can't find a way for it, this is what I will do. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Doing that is a very poor design choice.  It goes against what databases are optimised for.  It will be ineffieicnet, wasteful, and prone to inconsistencies if updates are interrupted or not done correctly.